# Gnome Shell CSS Properties for Menus

Tags: gnome, themes, css

I previously had a question about asking for elements in the GNOME Shell, but I deleted it because it was too broad.

So I am editing a`gnome-shell.css` file and I am looking everywhere but I cannot find where the color of the popup menus are. I see the css properties about the menus, but I cannot find a property that contains the main background color for them. In the following image, I  show the popup-menu I have. I would like to change the white color:

[image]

Comment: Same comment I made before best to ask this at Gnome support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes from popup menus are called `.popup-menu-*`.

This affects the applications menu, places, and other menus related to the system tray. The class `.popup-menu-item` styles each menu item, and `.popup-sub-menu` styles the menu that contains the shutdown, restart, etc. options you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that has guided me in the right direction!